Docker openwebui not able to access host ollama
First I want to admit I don't know much about Docker.
I've ollama inalled on an Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS bare metal. And I've installed Open Web UI via the Docker. I installed the container using the following command:
docker run -d -p 4000:8080 --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway -v open-webui:/app/backend/data --name open-webui --restart always ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main

as suggested by the instructions.
When I open the Open Web UI at localhost:4000 I'm able to open the page and go to Settings -> Connections and see: http://localhost:11434/ as the connection URL (which I'm able to open via the brower). But the page complains WebUI could not connect to Ollama.
Below are the things I've tried already:

Making ollama listen on a specific IP address and usign that in the Open Web API.
Using localhost, 127.0.0.1 and a specific IP address on the GUI, but the connection never came up.
Not sure what scenario I had but once I was able to see in /var/log/syslog some log entries from ollama where I could see 404 and I think some URL as //api or something.

Below are the error logs from the container:
INFO:apps.ollama.main:get_all_models()
ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: Cannot connect to host host.docker.internal:11434 ssl:default [Connection refused]
INFO:apps.ollama.main:get_all_models()
ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: Cannot connect to host host.docker.internal:11434 ssl:default [Connection refused]
INFO:apps.ollama.main:app.state.config.OLLAMA_BASE_URLS: ['http://host.docker.internal:11434']
INFO:     172.17.0.1:46474 - "POST /ollama/urls/update HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:apps.ollama.main:get_all_models()
ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: Cannot connect to host host.docker.internal:11434 ssl:default [Connection refused]

More errors
INFO:apps.ollama.main:get_all_models()
ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: http://host.docker.internal:11434:11434/api/tags
INFO:apps.ollama.main:get_all_models()
ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: http://host.docker.internal:11434:11434/api/tags
INFO:config:Saving 'OLLAMA_BASE_URLS' to config.json
INFO:apps.ollama.main:app.state.config.OLLAMA_BASE_URLS: ['http://host.docker.internal:11434:11434']
INFO:     172.17.0.1:32786 - "POST /ollama/urls/update HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

And more
INFO:apps.ollama.main:get_all_models()
ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: host.docker.internal:11434/api/tags
INFO:apps.ollama.main:get_all_models()
ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: host.docker.internal:11434/api/tags
INFO:config:Saving 'OLLAMA_BASE_URLS' to config.json
INFO:apps.ollama.main:app.state.config.OLLAMA_BASE_URLS: ['host.docker.internal:11434']
INFO:     172.17.0.1:57760 - "POST /ollama/urls/update HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:apps.ollama.main:get_all_models()
ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: host.docker.internal:11434/api/tags
INFO:apps.ollama.main:get_all_models()
ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: host.docker.internal:11434/api/tags
ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: host.docker.internal:11434/api/version
INFO:     172.17.0.1:57760 - "GET /ollama/api/version HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
INFO:apps.ollama.main:get_all_models()
ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: host.docker.internal:11434/api/tags
INFO:apps.ollama.main:get_all_models()
ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: host.docker.internal:11434/api/tags
INFO:     172.17.0.1:57760 - "GET /api/models HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

Looking for some help from the community.

These are the error logs I collected from the Container:

The settings should say host.docker.internal:11434 rather than using localhost

I've tried both host.docker.internal:11434 and 127.0.0.1:11434 in the UI Settings. Added the logs as well. Thanks.

localhost and 127.0.0.1 obviously refer to the Docker instance itself from within it. You need to know the IP address assigned by Docker (clearly 172.17.something  in your case).

Thanks folks for all the help. I reinstalled the docker using sudo docker run -d -p 4000:8080 --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway -v open-webui:/app/backend/data --name open-webui --restart always ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main
and then I used http://host.docker.internal:11434 in the connection setting and now the Open Web UI can talk to Ollama :D

@user13252132 can you please post the complete code on the answer

Solution: docker run -d -p 4000:8080 --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway -v open-webui:/app/backend/data -e OLLAMA_BASE_URL=http://host.docker.internal:11434 --name open-webui --restart always ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main

Changing port 3000 to 4000 works but there must be another solution. Why 3000 port started to cause problem. It was working correctly in first.

The fact that it's still trying to use "host.docker.internal" suggests that there might be a configuration problem within the Open WebUI container itself. Let's try a different approach:
docker stop open-webui
Now, let's try to override the DNS settings for the container. Stop and remove the existing container:
docker run -d --network="host" 
-v open-webui:/app/backend/data 
-e OLLAMA_API_BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:11434/api 
--add-host=host.docker.internal:127.0.0.1 
--dns 8.8.8.8 
--name open-webui 
ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main
